# Unable to use Warden in Sinatra App: env['warden'] returns nil

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, warden

I'm writing a Sinatra Rack App and I want to use Warden for authentication. I'm using heroku's toolbelt so I use foreman to run my app. I've found [some code](https://gist.github.com/557436) that's presumably supposed to get this working. Unfortunately, when I attempt to actually access the Warden env object, it is nil.

I've attempted to use the [sinatra_warden](https://github.com/jsmestad/sinatra_warden) gem, but it also has its [own bugs](https://github.com/jsmestad/sinatra_warden/issues/3) (might be related to this one).

config.ru:

```
require './web.rb'
use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/css", "/img", "/js"], :root => "public"
run MyApp
```

web.rb:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'warden'
require 'data_mapper'

require './config/datamapper.rb'
require './config/warden.rb' # I've tried this inside of MyApp, still didn't work

class MyApp < Sinatra::Base

  get '/test' do
    env['warden'].authenticate! # env['warden'] is nil :(
  end

end
```

config/warden.rb:

```
use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => ENV['SESSION_SECRET']

use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :password
  manager.failure_app = MyApp.new
end

Warden::Manager.serialize_into_session { |user| user.id }
Warden::Manager.serialize_from_session { |id| User.get(id) }

Warden::Manager.before_failure do |env,opts|
  # Sinatra is very sensitive to the request method
  # since authentication could fail on any type of method, we need
  # to set it for the failure app so it is routed to the correct block
  env['REQUEST_METHOD'] = "POST"
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:password) do
  def valid?
    params["email"] || params["password"]
  end

  def authenticate!
    u = User.authenticate(params["email"], params["password"])
    u.nil? ? fail!("Could not log in") : success!(u)
  end
end
```

Versions:

- Sinatra: 1.1.0
- Warden: 1.2.1
- Rack: 1.4.1
- Ruby: 1.9.3p194
- Foreman: 0.60.0

Any ideas how to use Warden the set up I've described?

(P.S. Out of curiosity, what exactly is the env variable?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rack internally uses the class [Rack::Builder](https://github.com/chneukirchen/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/builder.rb) to parse your config.ru file and wrap directives to build up the middleware components.

I believe your builder calls to `use` in `config/warden.rb` are getting ignored. It may work to remove the directives from that file and add them to the middleware stack in `config.ru`:

```
require './web.rb'

use Rack::Session::Cookie, :secret => ENV['SESSION_SECRET']

use Warden::Manager do |manager|
  manager.default_strategies :password
  manager.failure_app = MyApp.new
end

use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/css", "/img", "/js"], :root => "public"

run MyApp
```

Comment: Oh yeah, and the `env` variable represents the request environment; it's basically a hash of everything you want to know about the request (headers, request method, params, etc.)

Comment: I would agree with keeping the use call with either a sinatra file or a rack file. Sinatra is Rack based and so includes Rack. There is also a gem 'sinatra-warden' that is supposed to work with newer versions of these kinds of web apps. Just learning or maybe just discovering sinatra authentication strategies this week in aug. 2015.

Answer (score 2):

Put a link to your config/warden in your config.ru

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/warden'
```

Read the warden readme. Or look right in the lib/warden.rb

I put

```
Warden.test_mode!
```

in place of the env call at the /test path and get a nice blank page at

```
http://localhost:9292/test
```

Some bloggers have stated that there isn't a lot of documentation for warden but I disagree. There is a whole wiki. see https://github.com/hassox/warden/wiki

Take it slow and find out how to use middleware in Rack. Here's a very good article https://blog.engineyard.com/2015/understanding-rack-apps-and-middleware

I think maybe you might want to start out with tests as I found a good example and you could use it with your app.

```
ENV['RACK_ENV'] = 'test'
require 'test/unit'
require 'rack/test'

require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/web'

class AuthenticationTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  include Rack::Test::Methods

  def app
    WardenTest #MyApp
  end

  def test_without_authentication
    get '/protected'
    assert_equal 401, last_response.status
  end

  def test_with_bad_credentials
    authorize 'bad', 'boy'
    get '/protected'
    assert_equal 401, last_response.status
  end

  def test_with_proper_credentials
    authorize 'admin', 'admin'
    get '/protected'
    assert_equal 200, last_response.status
    assert_equal "You're welcome, authenticated client", last_response.body
  end
end
```

Then a few routes added to your app.

```
helpers do
  def protected!
    return if authorized?
    headers['WWW-Authenticate'] = 'Basic realm="Restricted Area"'
    halt 401, "Not authorized\n"
  end

  def authorized?
    @auth ||=  Rack::Auth::Basic::Request.new(request.env)
    @auth.provided? and @auth.basic? and @auth.credentials and     
    @auth.credentials == ['admin', 'admin']
  end
end

get '/' do
  "Everybody can see this page"
end

get '/protected' do
  protected!
  "You're welcome, authenticated client"
end
```

In my experience working with Ruby, it's always a good idea to start out with tests for any new project. I often test little pieces first though just to gain an understanding of how they work.

Once you get a better understanding of Rack, especially Rack::Builder, you can use

```
map '/test' do
  ...all the middleware needed
  run App
end
```

and try out different configurations to see which ones work best for your needs as I'm doing while I write this.

Enjoy! ;-)